# Having problems with scanf if a word is bigger than 7 characters

Tags: c, string, char, scanf

I'm reading some words off of the console, putting them in a list, and then printing them. For some reason, if I type something like

> qwertyu qwertyu

it prints **"1st word: qwertyu // 2nd word: qwertyu"**.
But if I type

> qwertyui qwertyui

it prints **"1st word: qwertyuiqwertyui // 2nd word: qwertyui"**.
Any word longer than 7 characters causes it to clone itself and I have no idea why it's happening.

Here's some of my code:

```
#include<stdio.h>
#include<string.h>
#include<stdlib.h>

int total_pal = 2000; //Total de palavras
int nelem = 0; //Numero de elementos da lista LISTA
int numero = 0; //Numero de elementos da lista FIM

typedef struct Palavra{ //Criando uma estrutura pra palavra
    char *caracs; //Consiste de caracteres
    int freq; //e sua freqência

}Palavra;

Palavra *lista; //Lista de palavras
Palavra *fim; //Lista de palavras depois do parse
Palavra *temp; //Lista temporaria para fazer ondernação

/*struct Palavra *newPalavra(char *caracs, int freq){
    struct Palavra *palavra = malloc(sizeof(struct Palavra)); //Alocando memoria pra palavra
    if (palavra == NULL)
        printf("Deu erro no malloc de palavra!");

    palavra->caracs = malloc (sizeof(char)); //Alocando memoria pros caracteres da palavra
    if(palavra->caracs == NULL){
        free(palavra);
        printf("Deu erro no malloc de caracter!");
    }

    palavra->caracs = strdup(caracs); //Define os caracteres dentro da estrutura como o char passado na chamada
    palavra->freq = freq; //Mesma coisa com a frequencia
    return palavra;
}*/

int busca(Palavra *fim, char *palavra){ //Busca palavra na lista
    int l = 0;
    while(l<numero && strcmp(fim[l].caracs, palavra) != 0){ //Equanto i for menor do que o numero total de palavras existentes e a palavra na lista for diferente da palavra procurada
        l++; //Vai somando até achar ou não a palavra
    }
return l; //retorna posição
}

void troca(Palavra *lista, int i, int j){ //Usada na ordenação
    *temp = lista[i];
    lista[i] = lista[j];
    lista[j] = *temp;
}

void ordena(Palavra *fim,int nelem){ //Ordena a lista fim em ordem decrescente de frequência
    for(int i = 0;i<(nelem-1);i++){
        for(int j = (i+1);j<nelem;j++){
            if (fim[i].freq<fim[j].freq){
                troca(fim,i,j);
            }
        }
    }
}

void alfabetica(Palavra *lista,int nelem){
    for (int i = 1; i < nelem; i++) {
      for (int j = 1; j < nelem; j++) {
         if (strcmp(&lista[j-1].caracs, &lista[j].caracs) > 0) {
            troca(lista,j,j-1);
         }
      }
   }
}

int main(){
    lista= malloc(sizeof(struct Palavra)*total_pal); //Aloca memoria pra lista usada pro scanf
    if (lista == NULL)
        printf("Deu erro!");

    temp= malloc(sizeof(struct Palavra)); //Aloca memoria pra lista temporaria usada na ordenação
    if (lista == NULL)
        printf("Deu erro!");

    fim= malloc(sizeof(struct Palavra)*total_pal); //Aloca memoria pra lista final
    if (fim == NULL)
        printf("Deu erro!");

    while(scanf("%s",&lista[nelem].caracs)!= EOF){ //Le input do console até chegar um EOF e adiciona tudo na lista
        nelem++;
    }

    alfabetica(lista,nelem); //Ordena a lista em ordem alfabetica

    for(int p=0;p<nelem;p++){ //Imprime as palavras junto com suas frequências
        printf("Palavra: %s\n",&lista[p].caracs);
    }

    for(int k = 0;k<nelem;k++){
        int pos = busca(fim,&lista[k].caracs);

        if(pos != numero){ //Palavra já consta
            fim[pos].freq++; //Incrementa a frequência dela

        }
        else if (numero == total_pal){
            printf("overflow!");
        }
        else if(pos == numero){ //Palavra não consta
            fim[pos].caracs = &lista[k].caracs; //Define a palavra na posição correta na lista fim como o pch
            fim[pos].freq = 1; //Define sua frequencia como 1
            numero++;
            //printf("adicionei\n");
        }
   }

    ordena(fim,numero); //Ordena a lista fim por frequencia

    for(int p=0;p<numero;p++){ //Imprime as palavras junto com suas frequências
        printf("Palavra: %s   Frequencia: %d\n",fim[p].caracs,fim[p].freq);
    }

    free(lista); //Libera a memoria usada nas listas
    free(temp);
    free(fim);
}
```

Comment: What is `Palavra`? Where do you allocate memory for the string? You don't call `newWord` anywhere it seems? And And if `lista` is an array of `Word` structures, then the expression `&lista[nelem].caracs` will give you a pointer *to the pointer* `caracs` (i.e. it's the type `char **`) which is not what `scanf` expects. A good compiler will be able to detect it and give you a warning about that.

Comment: Oh, and your `newWord` function have a memory leak of one byte every time it is called.

Comment: Several includes are missing as well. `nelem` is not defined. I still wonder how you were able to compile this piece of code ^^

Comment: Sorry, Palavra is Word. Forgot to change that. Do you think this memory leak is what's causing it?

Comment: As i said, it's just a part of my code. The entire thing is 120 lines long

Comment: You are wasting your time and our time unless you post a [minimal complete and verifiable example](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve). Make sure what you post compiles exactly as shown and is able to reproduce the problem. As already asked - why is `newWord` never called?

Comment: You're not even *calling* `newWord` so the memory leak is irrelevant, and it won't cause the problem either. The cause seems to be a you using a pointer *to a pointer* when you use the address-of operator in the `&lista[nelem].caracs` expression. That's what it looks like. And when you remove the address-of operator `&` then you will *still* have *undefined behavior* since you don't seem to initialize the pointer `caracs` anywhere.

Comment: You're right. Deleting newWord does nothing to my program. I guess i was using it before and forgot to delete it. I just edited the post with my entire code.

Comment: Bad idea to just delete `newWord`. You had it there for a good reason (even if not entirely correct yet). That was where `lista[nelem].caracs` is allocated. Now those pointers are garbage values and your `scanf` calls are writing to invalid memory.

Comment: @kaylum I just tried allocating memory to lista->caracs but i'm gettng the same problem. I know my code is a huge mess but it's actually working for words with less than 8 characters

Comment: "it's actually working". Code is never "working" if it fails any test case. It just means the bugs aren't triggered. We can't help you fix your code line by line. Especially since you keep changing the code - we can't really track the state of your code as it changes. But for starters `scanf("%s",&lista[nelem].caracs)` needs to be `scanf("%s",lista[nelem].caracs)`

Answer (score 0):

You need to allocate memory for the caracs value in each struct that you allocate.

```
 lista= malloc(sizeof(struct Palavra)*total_pal);
 int i;
 const int SIZE_STR = 100;
 for (i = 0; i < total_pal; i++) {
     lista[i].caracs = malloc(sizeof(char) * SIZE_STR);
 }
```